# HTML Variables used in paragraphs ect

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Is it possible to define string variables at the top of the page and then reference them in my HTML code? If so, how would I do this?

Here's an example of the code (how i assume it may look):

```
<script>
    var title = "Title"
    var desc = "Description"
</script>

<h1> title variable here </h1>
<p> desc variable here </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access JS variables in HTML. You need to make changes to the document within JavaScript.

```
document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = title;
```

This code looks for the first `<h1>` element in your document and sets everything within the element to the variable title. Take a look at the [JS Tutorial by W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp).

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Tutorials) is a better reference

Comment: Probably true but the W3-TryEditor is very beginner-friendly

Comment: Use jsFiddle or the stacksnippet here at SO

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, but you could grab the `innerHTML` and replace template variables e.g. surrounded by double-curly braces.

I recommend avoiding this, and instead use a templating library such as [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/)

```js
const
  title = 'Title',
  desc = 'Description',
  substitute = (text, replacements) =>
    text.replace(/\{\{(\w+)\}\}/g, (g0, g1) => replacements[g1]),
  substituteHtml = (el, replacements) =>
    el.innerHTML = substitute(el.innerHTML, replacements);

substituteHtml(document.body, { title, desc });
```

```html
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>{{desc}}</p>
```

---

### A better alternative

Example templating library usage using handlebars. This let's us build/modify HTML content safely.

```js
const
  context = {
    title: 'Title',
    desc: 'Description'
  },
  template = document.querySelector('#handlebars-demo').innerHTML,
  templateFn = Handlebars.compile(template);

document.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = templateFn(context);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<div class="output"></div>
<script id="handlebars-demo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p>{{desc}}</p>
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Only with JavaScript when the page loads, like this...

```html
<body onload="T.innerHTML=title; D.innerHTML=desc;">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var title = "Title",
      desc = "Description";
  </script>
  <h1 id="T"></h1>
  <p id="D"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Avoid using `window.T` as a replacement for `document.findElementById('T')`. It is bad practice and is not guaranteed to work in modern browsers. It was introduced by IE and was never adopted officially by ECMA.

Comment: Sorry I don't agree with that. I'm a browser author thanks.

Comment: Please see: [_"Do DOM tree elements with ids become global variables?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

Comment: Also inline onload is not recommended. Use window.addEventListener